# Encrypt password in App.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ado.net

I want to encrypt the password in connection string. When I make a connection to DB the connection string is openly stored in App.config and I need to find a way to keep only password encrypted.

Comment: Please check out this link for encrypting the password in the config file: http://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Lets say this is your connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="cs" connectionString="Data Source=myServerAddress;Initial Catalog=myDataBase;User Id=myUsername;Password=XXSDFASFDKSFJDKLJFDWERIODFSDFHSDJHKJNFJKSD;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Then you can do something like this:

```
string myCs = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString;

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder csb = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(myCs);
csb.Password = EncDecHelper.Decrypt(csb.Password);
myCs = csb.ToString();
```

You can write `EncDecHelper.Decrypt` by using samples from here: [Encrypt and decrypt a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)

Comment: But as I understand anyone can decrypt it back ... Besides I want just encrypt password.

Comment: @NDeveloper: i changed my answer, take a look.

Comment: I used the MySql version MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder after seeing this post, worked great, thanks.

Answer (score 21):

Use the [`connectionStrings`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bf7sd233(v=vs.100).aspx) configuration section and encrypt the whole section - instead of just the password.

This is safer as your app config will no longer have the server names and user names in plain text either.

There are how-to documents for encrypting configuration sections on MSDN for [RSA](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650304.aspx) or [DPAPI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647398.aspx).

Comment: Is there a way to make it work for an App.config file instead of just Web.config? Thanks for the answer though! +1

Comment: @One-One http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803188/encrypting-connectionstrings-section-utility-for-app-config

Comment: "This content is outdated and is no longer being maintained." Should it still be used? @Oded

Answer (score 0):

Maybe decrypt connection string from your config before application was loaded.

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to the other answers, isn't it better to use the file in Source Control as a template, with just dev/test encrypted connection strings so that it works in dev/test.

For production (or other environments the app is deployed to), the encrypted credentials file is generated separately to the specified template format, managed/updated/deployed separately, has appropriate security permissions applied, never seen by anyone other than DBA/DevOps.