# Encryption of SQL Login details

Tags: c#, sql, .net, t-sql, database-administration

I've SQL login username and password. i will use in connection string in c# program to retrieve data from the database but I don't want to show password. Is there any way i can encrypt it so that no one can see password and also not easy to decrypt it.

Answer (score 2):

This article (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dx0f3cf2(v=vs.85).aspx) exmplains how to encrypt your connection strings in the Web.config.

This answer about app.config encryption ([Encrypting connectionStrings section - utility for app.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803188/encrypting-connectionstrings-section-utility-for-app-config))