# Ecrypt password in app.config

Tags: c#, entity-framework-4, sql-server-ce-4

I am using `Entity Framework` to create a SQLServer connection of database with a password:

```
connectionString="DataSource=|DataDirectory|DB.sdf;Password=abc
```

How can I protect the password while using Entity Framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
    ConnectionStringsSection oSection = Configuration.ServiceConfiguration.GetConnectionStrings();
    if(!oSection.SectionInformation.IsLocked && !oSection.SectionInformation.IsProtected)
    {
        oSection.SectionInformation.ProtectSection("RSAProtectedConfigurationProvider"); 
        oSection.CurrentConfiguration.Save();
    }
```

Comment: Does this work with entity framework, because the code above will encrypt the connection string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the server, you can use the web config encryption tool from cmd. I create a .bat file in the same folder as my web.config containing:

```
aspnet_regiis -pef connectionStrings .
aspnet_regiis -pef appSettings .
pause
```

This will encrypt the connectionStrings whole section and in my case, the appSettings whole section too.

To Decrypt, do:

```
aspnet_regiis -pdf connectionStrings .
aspnet_regiis -pdf appSettings .
pause
```

You will need to run this from the server though.

Answer (score 0):

You can write `EncDecHelper.Decrypt` by using samples from here: **[Encrypt/Decrypt string in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/202011/encrypt-decrypt-string-in-net)**

You will find the related information from here: **[Encrypt password in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config)**