# Using Kerberos with WinForm project

Tags: winforms, authentication

We have a project with Dal layers and View layer which is written in WinForm.
Those are separate project in same solution.
We have app.config file in the view project and in the Dal project that store the user name and the password of the DB.
I ask by the boss to check the possibility to work with Kerberos to avoid the need to write hard coded the password in the app.config.
I know that i have the option to encrypt the app.config as mention here  [Encrypt password in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config)
Still, id like to know how should i approach this thing to work with Kerberos. 
What changes need to be done in the C# code, app.config file, databse server etc..

Thanx

P.S We do use with Kerbaros authentication in our compeny for other project.
This is how the authentication is right now:
1. Against the active directory: the user must be in some group, and of course we check the password that he type if it's much to one that store in the AD
2. Against a table in the DB

So with the kerbaros we don't need the user to type any password, right?

Comment: What database server?

Comment: sql server 2014

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enable [Integrated Security](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder.integratedsecurity(v=vs.110).aspx) on the connection string. This will use Kerberos (if properly configured) or NTLM. Read [Authentication in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server).