# Hide passwords from windows forms application .exe.config file

Tags: .net, winforms, encryption, passwords, config

When Windows forms app builds, it generates a "myApplication.exe.config" file and it contains passwords. This release build will be copied to many different machines and users to use (not on a server in any way).

How do I hide these passwords from the customers?

Comment: *Trivially* you can store a base64 encoded string of the encrypted password then decode & decrypt when you need to.  In general there is no way to do this so that the user cannot capture the password with a little effort/know how.

Comment: Thanks, I only need a simple encryption, so that human would not understand when opened with a text editor. Any suggestions?

Comment: The ProtectedData class is simple to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.protecteddata

Comment: Thanks Alex, If I would encrypt lets say the app.config, would my coleagues be able to edit the solution from their machines?

Comment: I ment the app.config

Comment: Checkout this link: https://weblogs.asp.net/jongalloway/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Encrypt password in App.config](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5522879/encrypt-password-in-app-config)

Comment: thanks gunnerone, I've already tried similar methods, If I encrypt the file in any way, then my coleagues wount be able to access it. Is there a way to just generate a .dll instead of exe.config?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've moved out all sensitive lines with usernames and passwords in to a seperate txt/xml file.

Created a seperate project that encrypts any text/xml file using a hard coded key.

Copied the hard coded key in to the main project.

Now the project can read encrypted text/html credentials, decrypt it, and store it in a variable and use it wherever it needs to.